# Add language localisation to javascript alert?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, translation

I have a series of language files for a plugin.  It all works as expected.

If I add a javascript alert, how do I translate the text of the alert?

PHP would be `__('example text', 'context');`

What is the JS equivalent for `alert('example text');`

Is it even possible?

Comment: to do that, you need to translate the string in PHP and pass the value to JavaScript with this function : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Ahhh...cool, thanks.  Can you add that as an answer so I can accept it and maybe it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do this without [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script). I do it this way with forms and scripts when I want to visualize the output inside a HEREDOC. I name a variable something like the string in my native English, l18n it first, and then put it where it goes in the heredoc:

```
$someText = __('Some Text', 'myPluginSlug');
$helloWorld = __('Hello World!!', 'myPluginSlug');

$output = <<<OUTPUT

   $someText

   <script>
      alert('$helloWorld');
   </script>

OUTPUT;

return $output;
```